# Running a Python Subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

All,

I have read several threads on how to run subprocesses in python and none of them seem to help me. It's probably because I don't know how to use them properly. I have several methods that I would like to run at the same time rather than in sequence and I thought that the subprocess module would do this for me.

```
def services():
     services = [method1(),
            method2(),
            method3(),  
            mrthod4(),
            method5()]
     return services

def runAll():
    import subprocess
    for i in services():
        proc = subprocess.call(i,shell=True)
```

The problem with this approach is that method1() starts and method2() doesn't start until 1 finishes. I have tried several approaches including using subprocess.Popen[] in my services method with no luck. Can anyone lend me a hand on how to get methods 1-5 running at the same time?

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 3.2.x the concurrent futures module makes this sort of things very easy.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Python documentation `subprocess.call()` waits for the command to complete. You should directly use the `subprocess.Popen` objects which will give you the flexibility you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use & to execute them asynchronously.  Here is an example:

```
 subprocess.call("./foo1&", shell=True)
 subprocess.call("./foo2&", shell=True)
```

This is just like the ordinary unix shell.

EDIT:  Though there are multiple, much better ways to do this.  See the other answers for some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Python threads are more appropriate to what you are looking for: http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html or even the multiprocessing module: http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.

Comment: Threads are likely not appropriate at all, unless the tasks are I/O-bound or the OP is running Jython. Multiprocessing is a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

By saying `method1()`, you're calling the function and waiting for it to return. (It's a function, not a method.)

If you just want to run a bunch of heavy-duty function in parallel and collect their result, you can use [`joblib`](http://packages.python.org/joblib/):

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

functions = [fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4]

results = Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(f)() for f in functions)
```

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.call()` blocks until the process completes.

`multiprocessing` sounds more appropriate for what you are doing.

for example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f1():
    while True:
        print 'foo'

def f2():
    while True:
        print 'bar'

def f3():
    while True:
        print 'baz'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for func in (f1, f2, f3):
        Process(target=func).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

subprocess does not make the processes asynchronous. What you are trying to achieve can be done using multithreading or multiprocessing module.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently, and solved it like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def parallelfuncs(funcs, args, results, bad_value = None):
    p = Pool()
    waiters = []
    for f in funcs:
        waiters.append(p.apply_async(f, args, callback = results.append))
    p.close()
    for w in waiters:
        if w.get()[0] == bad_value:
            p.terminate()
    return p
```

The nice thing is that the functions *funcs* are executed in parallel on args (kind of the reverse of map), and the result returned. The Pool of multiprocessing uses all processors and handles job execution.

w.get blocks, if that wasn't clear.

For your use case, you would call

```
results = []
parallelfuncs(services, args, results).join()
print results
```